# SSIS 2008R2 Disable property stored back at design time from run time

Tags: ssis

I've got a package where most of the activities run every day, but some only run on specific working days (mostly WD1). I have a variable that indicates the WD index within the month (e.g. 2 Jan 2019 is WD1 as the 1st was a bank holiday in the UK). I've set an expression on an Execute SQL task such that the Disable property is evaluated by (@WDindex != 1), i.e. it gets disabled when WDindex is anything other than 1.

In BIDS, I enable all the tasks and run the package, let it run through and it behaves correctly. Once it is executed and I click the stop button, I find that the tasks that wouldn't have run today are still disabled. i.e. the Disable value passes back from runtime to design time values. They were enabled before running.

So I have a few questions:

1. Is this an obscure bug, or is it designed like this?
2. If a container/task is disabled, with an expression on its disable property, will it run the expression to work out whether to re-enable it?
3. Once on the SSIS server, does this behaviour continue? i.e. after running, is the value of the Disable flag stored back into the stored package?

Obviously, I want the Disable property of the tasks to re-evaluate every time the package runs.

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: Some tasks will be shown as enabled/disabled inconsistently on visual studio, but they will always work as expected if properly configured.

Comment: In your one example you are working with a property, how about doing it with an IF statement in your SQL.

Comment: @KeithL This would be a way to do it. My user (i.e. the provider of user requirements) appears to have a tendency of changing her mind about when during the month a task runs as well as its frequency, depending on the volumes/nature of records coming through during UAT. I'd rather control this in one place, in the SSIS package, than in the individual sprocs.

Comment: Pass a parameter, you can even set that up from agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done some experiments, I've determined the following:

1. I imagine it's a bug and not a feature, but it doesn't really matter, and yes, the resulting runtime value definitely DOES write-over the design time value.
2. The Disable property is re-evaluated adequately so that if it's value were to change during running, the task will execute this. I tested this using a loop container that will run indefinitely, and a single ExecuteSQL task which is only enabled in the first second of every minute. The ExecuteSQL task write the current datetime to a simple table. The table slowly filled with datetimes for the first second of each minute the task ran.

`InitExpression: @WDindex = DATEPART("s", GETDATE())
    EvalExpression: true
    AssignExpression: @WDindex = DATEPART("s", GETDATE())`

For the ExecuteSQL task:

```
INSERT Sandbox.dbo.Log
    (CreatedDateTime,
    Description)
VALUES
    (GETDATE(),
    'Task not disabled')
```

3. I don't know, but given the result of 2, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is the design-time experience and the run-time experience. At design-time, the value of the variable @WDindex is ...whatever it is. I'll assume 1 for this answer. You have tasks enabled/disabled based on the value and that is reflected in the designer.

When the package runs, the value of @WDIndex changes to be the current/run-time value. Here, I assume it's non-1 so things correctly enable in your package. When the SSIS package execution completes, it doesn't save current state. Instead, that workspace is reset to the default design-time values in anticipation of the next run.

Expressions are evaluated every time they are accessed. If you had some method of toggling @WDIndex in between Tasks, you'd see this. An easier way to see this for yourself is to look at the GetDate() function. Every time you ask inspect it, the value will change - unless you explicitly store out the value to a variable via Script Task or the Expression Task (2012+).

Comment: I think the behaviour is different. On returning from runtime to design time, the Disable property of the tasks at the end of runtime then become the design time values. i.e. the design time values are overwritten.

My question is, for a disabled task, does the disable property get re-evaluated if the expression it is defined by changes (the task is disabled after all)?